# ssh concatenating keyboard characters

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I am sshing into a mac running zsh but each character that I type is remembered and repeated. For example, if it type `exit`, I see `eexexiexit` on the screen but the command `exit` is executed.

If I type directly on the remote machine, there is not a problem so it is the communication via ssh that is the issue. I have no idea how to solve. Any suggestions?

Comment: After some further investigating, I realise that the problem is that I have `$TERM=tmux-256color.terminfo` on the client while the mac that I am sshing into is set to `screen-256color`.  Is there a way to change the `$TERM` variable when logging into the mac?

Answer (score 2):

I realised that I just needed to ssh into the remove server with the following command: `'TERM=screen-256color ssh ...`